# Error in Jackson's 'Classical Electrodynamics' definition of Matrix Multiplication (Eq. 6.142)?

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, textbook-erratum

I am reading Jackson's 'Classical Electrodynamics' (3rd Edition), and as an exercise I was trying to go through equation 6.142 on page 268. I was wondering if he got this definition of the matrix multiplication incorrect? Jackson writes:

$$\sum_\alpha a_{\alpha\beta}a_{\alpha \gamma}=\delta_{\beta \gamma}$$

But, when explicitly expanding the summation for a 2x2 matrix I get an error for the $a_{11}$ entry (all entries as a matter of fact):

$$a_{11} = a_{11}a_{11}+a_{21}a_{21}$$

When it should read:

$$a_{11} = a_{11}a_{11}+a_{12}a_{21}$$

This 'error' can be corrected using the matrix multiplication summation equation:

$$\sum_\alpha a_{\beta\alpha}a_{\alpha \gamma}=\delta_{\beta \gamma}$$

My Einstein summation abilities are limited and very rusty, so I just thought I'd check in to make sure I am understanding things correctly, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More context which confirms [Lagerbaer's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/304714/44126), since my Jackson is at hand:

> A rotation in three dimensions is a linear transformation of the coordinates of a point such that the sum of the squares of the coordinates remains invariant.
>   Such a transformation is called an orthogonal transformation.
>   The transformed coordinates $x_\alpha'$ are given in terms of the original coordinates $x_\beta$ by
>   $$
> x_\alpha'= \sum_\beta a_{\alpha\beta}x_\beta \tag{6.141}
> $$
>   The requirement to have $(\mathbf{x'})^2 = (\mathbf x)^2$ restricts the real transformation coefficients $a_{\alpha\beta}$ to be orthogonal,
>   $$
> \sum_\alpha a_{\alpha\beta} a_{\alpha\gamma} = \delta_{\beta\gamma} \tag{6.142}
> $$
>   The inverse transformation has $(a^{-1})_{\alpha\beta} = a_{\beta\alpha}$ and the square of the determinant of the matrix $(a)$ is equal to unity. ...

So what you have here is not a general expression for matrix multiplication, but a restriction on this particular matrix in order to give it the symmetries it needs to represent rotations.

Answer (score 4):

That equation doesn't define general matrix multiplication. For general matrix multiplication, the formula is

$$C= AB: C_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} B_{kj}$$

Translating his summation into a matrix multiplication would mean

$$\delta = a^T a$$
as you can deduce from the correct matrix multiplication formula I just gave.

If $\delta$ happens to be the Kronecker-$\delta$, then what this equation expresses is that matrix  $a$ is *orthogonal*. I don't have a copy of Jackson at hand to check for the context though.

It's not an *error* per se, it's just that the equation you provide is, indeed, not the general definition of matrix multiplication, but rather a special case of multiplying a matrix with its own transpose.